# Django update displayed contents with the correct subjects when user selects grade year

Tags: python, html, django

I want it so that when I select a grade year the specific subject for that grade year will appear.

Here's my test.html file.

```
<select id="id_of_select" name="subject">
        <option>--</option>
             {% for ylvl in edulevel %}
       <option value="{% for sub in subj %}
              {{sub.Description}}<br>
      {% endfor %}">{{ylvl.Description}}
    </option>

    {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <button id="btn">Show selected</button>

    <div id="display">
    </div>
      <script>
       function show_selected() {
         var selector = document.getElementById('id_of_select');
         var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
         document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = value;
                                }
         document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',show_selected);
          </script>
```

The Python file.
    #views.py
    def test(request):
        edulevel = EducationLevel.objects.all()
        id=request.GET.get('id_of_select')
        print(id)
        subj = Subject.objects.all()

```
    context = {
        'edulevel':edulevel,
        'subj':subj
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/test.html',context)
```

I need your help to make it so that when the select the grade year that the subject for that grade will appear within the display element.

Comment: Could you please specify your needs?
To help, I'd suggest you share models, to separate HTML and Python Code.

How do you want to filter your data? With GET params? Through POST data or even include year in your request path?

Comment: I cleaned up your grammar, and I tried to clean up your title some. I don't know what you're truly asking as I've not worked with Django before.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is for the 2nd select to be filled once the first has been - given you haven't given all your models, here is an example with Car Make and Car Model.

Consider 2 **Models**, one for a Car Make (eg Ford) and one for each Car Model (eg Fiesta) produced

```
class CarMake (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class CarModel (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    car_make = models.ForeignKey(
        CarMake,
        on_delete = models.SET_NULL,
        null = True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

We'll want a **form** to display our model data so here I'm giving a simple search form.  Note, I want to amend the Car Model list in `__init__` because I want it empty until a Car Make is selected

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    car_make = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget = forms.Select(
            attrs = {
                'class' : "make-categories"
            }
        ),
        queryset = CarMake.objects.all(),
        required=False
    )
    car_model = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget = forms.Select(
            attrs = {
                'class' : "make-categories"
            }
        ),
        queryset = CarModel.objects.all(),
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:  
        model = Car
        fields = ['car_make','car_model']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['car_make'].empty_label = 'Make'        
        self.fields['car_model'].empty_label = 'Model'
        try: self.fields['car_model'].queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(car_make=initial['car_make'])
        except: self.fields['car_model'].queryset = CarModel.objects.none()
```

I create a **template** with the form.  You'll notice 2 URLs.  One is for the actual search, the other to load the car models associated with a given make.

```
<form id="searchForm" data-models-url="{% url 'ajax_load_models' %}" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-4">
            {{ form.car_make }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4">
            {{ form.car_model }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search></button>
</form>
```

This **javascript** will call the relevant url and get the return data

```
$("#id_car_make").change(function () {
    var url = $("#searchForm").attr("data-models-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
    var carMakeId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

    $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
        data: {
            'car_make': carMakeId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
            $("#id_car_model").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
        }
    });

});
```

These are the **urls.py** called

```
path('search/', views.TextSearch.as_view(), name="search"),
path('ajax/load-models/', views.load_models, name="ajax_load_models"),
```

This **view** called from the javascript takes the selected Car Make and provides a list of models using the car_model_dropdown_list_options template

```
def load_models(request):
    car_make_id = request.GET.get('car_make')
    car_models = CarModel.objects.filter(car_make_id=car_make_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'leases/partials/car_model_dropdown_list_options.html', {'car_models': car_models})
```

The **car_model_dropdown_list_options** template outputs the resultant list of Car Models into the Select using the Javascript above it is put in the correct div, namely id_car_model.

```
    <option value="">Model</option>
    {% for car_model in car_models %}
    <option value="{{ car_model.pk }}">{{ car_model.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```